# Angular testing async pipe does not trigger the observable

Tags: javascript, angular, testing

I want to test a component that uses the async pipe. This is my code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
    <div>{{ number | async }}</div>
  `
})
class AsyncComponent {
  number = Observable.interval(1000).take(3)
}

fdescribe('Async Compnent', () => {
  let component : AsyncComponent;
  let fixture : ComponentFixture<AsyncComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ AsyncComponent ]
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AsyncComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should emit values', fakeAsync(() => {

    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('div')).nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe('0');

});
```

But the test failed. It's seems Angular does not execute to Observable from some reason. What I am missing?

When I'm trying to log the observable with the `do` operator, I don't see any output in the browser console.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell, you can't use `fakeAsync` with the async pipe. I would love to be proven wrong, but I experimented for a while and couldn't get anything to work. Instead, use the `async` utility (which I alias as `realAsync` to avoid confusion with the `async` keyword) and `await` a Promise-wrapped `setTimeout` instead of using `tick`.

```
import { async as realAsync, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AsyncComponent } from './async.component';

function setTimeoutPromise(milliseconds: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => { 
    setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
  });
}

describe('AsyncComponent', () => {
  let component: AsyncComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AsyncComponent>;
  let element: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(realAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AsyncComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AsyncComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should emit values', realAsync(async () => {
    await setTimeoutPromise(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(element.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML).toEqual('0');
  }));
});
```

Comment: thanks, that actually did it for me! But the fixture.detectChanges(); is also instrumental. I had one already at the end of the beforeChanges, like you, but that wasn't enough

Comment: You can definitely use `fakeAsync` tests for components that use the `async` pipe. Maybe the problems you've had are related to some need to flush the microtask queue at the right times? I use a helper I've created for my component tests that usually takes care of all those kinds of details for me: [ComponentContextNext](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-libs/ng-dev/classes/componentcontextnext.html).

Comment: Thanks man, this approach works perfectly!

Comment: tried using fakeAsync, done, setTimeout in test but nothing worked. This worked fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, I'm surprised nobody looked up any real solution.

**Possible solutions**

- Your template might not be rendered in your test, especially if you are overriding it. So, the | async operation won't trigger.
- You aren't using `fixture.detectChanges()` enough to allow template rendering. Rendering occurs after OnInit stage. So make sure you use fixture.detectChanges at least 2 times.
- Maybe you have `setTimeout` operations pending, for example `debounce(100)` would require a `tick(100)` to resolve (within a fakeAsync test).

Cheers