# Testing a property which is an observable without having to subscribe to it in the component

Tags: angular, jestjs, rxjs

Given there is this component which uses an async pipe to display content in a template via an observable property. In the following example this observable property is named `showMe$: Observable<boolean>;`

All works well when I run the application. However, when I'm running the test it does not emit anything via the observable. I guess because the subscription does not happen:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <p *ngIf="this.showMe$ | async">Hello!</p>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Select(MyStore.foo) public foo$: Observable<string>;

  public showMe$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.showMe$ = this.foo$.pipe(
      last(),
      map((someValue) => {
        return !!someValue
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the test:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let scheduler: TestScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    stub.foo$: new Subject();

    stub.Store = {
      select: selector => {
        switch (selector) => {
          case MyStore.foo:
            return stub.foo$;
          default:
            return new Subject();
        }
      }
    }

    scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      // ...
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges(); // OnInit
  });

  it('should return true when a value is provided in another observable', fakeAsync(() => {

    // this provide the store with a value
    stub.foo$.next('trivial string');

    // somehow nothing happens, this is not evaluated
    scheduler.run(({expectObservable}) => {
      expectObservable(component.showMe$).toBe('a', { a: true });
    });

    tick();
  }));
});
```

But that does not pass, and it will return the following error:

[image]

When I refactor the component to use a BehaviorSubject rather than an Observable, then it does work. Probably because then a subscription is done in the component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <p *ngIf="this.showMe$ | async">Hello!</p>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Select(MyStore.foo) public foo$: Observable<string>;

  public showMe$ = BehaviorSubject(false);

  private destroyed$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  ngOnInit() {

    // preferably no subscription
    this.foo$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))
      .subscribe((value) => {
         this.showMe$.next(!!someValue);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```

This works!

But I'd rather not since as you can see I have to write another observable (`this.destroyed$`) and manage that subscription myself rather than let Angular take care of this all via the async pipe.

Comment: Hmm, it might not be possible to use fakeAsync with the async pipe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821512/angular-testing-async-pipe-does-not-trigger-the-observable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular testing async pipe does not trigger the observable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821512/angular-testing-async-pipe-does-not-trigger-the-observable)

Comment: I've tried the examples in that post, but that's not working. The subscription needs to happen somehow.

Comment: Can't you subscribe to showMe$ in the test and put the expectation in the subscription?

Answer (score 0):

I've always had trouble with fakeAsync, so when it comes to testing observables, I like to follow this pattern:

```
it('Observable should do something', (done) => {
  // Arrange
  const mockObservable = new Subject(); // you already have this part
  
  // Assert (weird huh? it's just to handle the async logic)
  mockObservable.subscribe(() => {
    expect(...);
    done();
  );
  
  // Act
  mockObservable.next('mockValue');
});
```

Of course you can add pipe(last())... and everything when you subscribe to your mock obsevable as well.

I hope it helps! And I agree, if your scenario does not require BehaviorSubject , don't force it. It will cause you more headaches than satisfactions.